# Intent not being call despite Image button being initialiized

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, imagebutton

Have created an imagebutton: facebook icon and twitter icon. Hence, when user clicks on either icon, it will call on the new intent respectively; henceif user were to click the facebook icon, it will call on the intent of facebook.class.

However, when user clicks on either the facebook icon or twitter icon, it is unresponsive and it calls on a different intent within the same method. Can anyone, please help? thanks

XML code:

```
 <!-- The navigation drawer:right drawer-->
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/preview_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="#D8D8D8"
    android:typeface="serif" >


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/preview_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"              
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Product Preview"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:typeface="serif" 
            android:textSize="20sp"/>  

 <ImageButton
     android:id= "@+id/facebook_icon"
     android:src= "@drawable/facebook"
     android:paddingRight="10dp" 
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:background="@color/transparent" 
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/twitter_icon"/>
  <ImageButton 
     android:id= "@+id/twitter_icon"
     android:src= "@drawable/twitter_icon" 
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/transparent" 
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
     android:clickable="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>


    </LinearLayout>
...
```

Code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            //DAPO-DEV02:20150107: Social Media Sharing: Twitter

                ImageView TwitterBtn = (ImageView) mContex.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);
                TwitterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContex.getApplicationContext(),
                                ShareTwitter.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });



                //DAPO-DEV02:20150107: Social Media Sharing: Facebook
                ImageButton FacebookBtn = (ImageButton) mContex.findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon);
                FacebookBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContex.getApplicationContext(),
                                ShareFacebook.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                ProductImage =(ImageView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
                String imgFilePath = url + imageLargename;
                imageLoader.displayImage(imgFilePath, ProductImage, options);


                ProductImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(mContex,
                                "Pinch & Zoom To See Large Photo.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String imgFilePath = url + imageLargename;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                mContex.getApplicationContext(),
                                FullScreenViewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("path", imgFilePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                });

                //END OF EDITED VERSION TO DISPLAY VIEW FOR SELECTED FRAGMENT ITEM-19/11/2014
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you need to initialise the image button and set the on click listener inside the adapter and not in the onitemclicked

Comment: why you are setting `setOnClickListener` for ImageButton in onItemClick ? Note onItemClick method code only work when you press ListView row

Comment: @Simar meaning??? I dont get you

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK "onItemClick" is set for the gridView item and the resulting page is a preview fragment page while, the image button within the preview fragment can clicked for user to access either facebook or twitter. What do you mean that onItemClick only works when press ListView row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to decipher the problem and have come out with a solution that will call on the secondary intent:

Code:

```
//DAPO-DEV02:20150107: Social Media Sharing: Twitter

final ImageButton TwitterBtn = (ImageButton) mContex.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);
TwitterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String cKey = "MNjFvsNstiMXcddTLc4J0IsHa";
                        String cSecret = "NgziPWnykalqAeMZhDUygqAYS89qJtVsehv9aQhLSlZW2myZXp";
                        final String tw="";



                        if (shareTwitter == null)
                            shareTwitter = new ShareTwitter(cKey, cSecret, ((android.app.Activity) getActivity()),
                                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.twitter_icon);

                        if (socialBgAsyncTask == null) {
                            socialBgAsyncTask = (SocialBgAsyncTask) new SocialBgAsyncTask();
                            socialBgAsyncTask.execute();
                        }
                        if (twResponse == null) {
                            twResponse = "";
                            try {

                                String twitterURL = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";
                                try {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    i.setData(Uri.parse(twitterURL+Uri.encode(tw)));
                                    startActivity(i);
                                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can't tweet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Posting Twitter data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Processing post data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
});

//DAPO-DEV02:20150108: Edited version for Social Media Sharing: facebook and twitter
private class SocialBgAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("----------SocialBgAsyncTask----------", "doInBackground");
        long result = 0;
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            publishProgress(0);
        } while (!exitAsync);
        return result;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        // ====================TWITTER
        if (twResponse != null && !twResponse.equals("")) {
            if (twResponse.equals("success"))
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message has been successfully Tweeted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed tweeting message, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            twResponse = null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        Log.i("----------SocialBgAsyncTask ----------", "onPostExecute");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply replace

```
ImageView TwitterBtn = (ImageView) mContex.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);
```

with

```
ImageButton TwitterBtn = (ImageButton) mContex.findViewById(R.id.twitter_icon);
```